# Doubts regarding this pseudocode for the perceptron algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, perceptron

[image]

I am trying to implement the perceptron algorithm above. But I have two questions:

1. Why do we just update `w (weight)` variable once? Shouldn't there be separate `w` variables for each `Xi`? Also, not sure what `w = 0d` means mathematically in the initialization.
2. What is the mathematical meaning of

   ```
   yi(< xi,w >+b)
   ```

I kinda know what the meaning inside the bracket is but not sure about the `yi()` part.

Comment: The expression <xi, w> could be the dot product between the vectors xi and w. And yi(<xi,w>+b) could mean the product between yi and (<xi,w>+b).

Comment: Please, try to formulate descriptive titles for your question(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) You can think of 'yi' as a function that depends on w, xi and b.
let's say for a simple example, y is a line that separates two different classes. In that case, y can be represented as y = wx+b. Now, if you use 
w = 0,x = 1 and b = 0 then y = 0.

For your given algorithm, you need to update your weight **w**, when the output of y is less than or equal to 0.

So, if you look carefully, you are not updating **w** once, as it is inside an if statement which is inside a for loop.

For your algorithm, you will get **n** numbers of output y based on **n** numbers of input x for each iteration of t. Here 'i' is used for indexing both input as xi and output as yi.

So, long story short, out of **n** numbers of input x, you only need to update the **w** when the output y for the corresponding input x will be less than or equal to zero (for each iteration of t).

(1) I have already mentioned **w** is not updated once.

Let's say you know that any output value greater(<) than 0 is the correct answer. So if you get an output which is less than or equal to zero then there is a mistake in your algorithm and you need to fix it. This is what your algorithm is doing by updating the **w** when the output is not matching the desired one.

Here **w** is represented as a vector and it is initialized as zero.